# Kinetic Energy of a Body about Instantaneous Axis of Rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, moment-of-inertia

When we write the expression for the kinetic Energy of a rotating body, we write is as
$$E = \frac{I_{\text{CM}}{\omega}^2}{2} + \frac{M{V_{\text{CM}}}^2}{2}$$

So, basically we wrote the expression as $$E_{\text{body/ground}} = E_{\text{body/CM}} + E_{\text{CM/ground}}$$

However, I want to consider a case where I write the expression about a point which is at rest. For example, if I take a cylinder rolling without slipping on a surface, can I write it as
$$E= \frac{I_{\text{IAOR}}{\omega}^2}{2}$$
where IAOR is the instantaneous axis of rotation, because it is at rest?

Comment: Yes, since motion wrt IAOR will be purely rotational, so translation KE will be zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple to see how the equation holds mathematically, $$E= K.E._{trans} + K.E._{rot} \\ \implies E= \frac{I_{\text{CM}}{\omega}^2}{2} + \frac{M{V_{\text{CM}}}^2}{2} \\ \implies E = \frac{(I_{\text{CM}} + MR_{CM}^2){\omega}^2}{2} \\ \implies E=\frac{I_{IOAR}\omega^2}{2}$$

since about the IOAR $V_{CM}= R_{CM}\omega $and $I_{IOAR} = I_{CM} + MR_{CM}^2$
where $R_{CM}$ is the distance of center of mass from the instantaneous axis of rotation.

You could also say that it is purely rotational motion so you can use $E=\frac{I\omega^2}{2}$ but you cannot say it is at rest.

Comment: I meant that the IAOR is at rest for the instant.